# Force remove mounted windows share through terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, mount, file-sharing, smb

I have a Windows share mounted in OSX 10.9 Finder (through <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) that acts bizarre every so often (can't log in sometimes, randomly disconnects from the GUI claiming it can't access the mounted volume).

Usually I have to reboot to force-disconnect this mounted SMB drive; is there a way to do it through terminal? (Like say, using `mount`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `umount`:

`umount -f /your/mountpoint`

(`-f` forcibly removes the mount point)

Answer (score 0):

Try...

1. `diskutil unmountDisk force /Volumes/DISK_NAME`
2. `diskutil unmount /dev/disk0`

To get the `disk0`, which is the Identifier, you can run `diskutil list` in terminal to see which one it is. See http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/13/mount-unmount-drives-from-the-command-line-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Don't see why this needs to get downvoted, as it is a viable solution.